# Callable Cloud Function error: Response is missing data field

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-functions

Don't know how to get responce from cloud function in flutter.

My cloud function

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

exports.testDemo = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  return response.status(200).json({msg:"Hello from Firebase!"});
 });
```

My flutter code

```
///Getting an instance of the callable function:
    try {
      final HttpsCallable callable = CloudFunctions.instance.getHttpsCallable(
        functionName: 'testDemo',);

      ///Calling the function with parameters:
      dynamic resp = await callable.call();
      print("this is responce from firebase $resp");

    } on CloudFunctionsException catch (e) {
      print('caught firebase functions exception');
      print(e.code);
      print(e.message);
      print(e.details);
    } catch (e) {
      print('caught generic exception');
      print(e);
    }
```

flutter: caught firebase functions exception
flutter: INTERNAL
flutter: Response is missing data field.
flutter: null

Comment: You can't call an HTTP type function (onRequest) using the Callable functions SDK.  You will need to use a callable type function instead (onCall).  https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use

```
exports.testDemo = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  return {msg:"Hello from Firebase!"};
});
```

in cloud functions. [Callable](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.https#.onCall) is different than [Request](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.https#.onRequest)

When you call the functions you need to add the parameters:

change:

```
 // Calling a function without parameters is a different function!
  dynamic resp = await callable.call();
```

to:

```
dynamic resp = await callable.call(
     <String, dynamic>{
       'YOUR_PARAMETER_NAME': 'YOUR_PARAMETER_VALUE',
     },
);
```

as described [here](https://pub.dev/packages/cloud_functions)

then to print the response:

```
print(resp.data)
print(resp.data['msg'])
```

The Firebase Functions for flutter example [here](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/tree/master/packages/cloud_functions/example) and [here](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/blob/master/packages/cloud_functions/example/lib/main.dart)

Comment: i use onCall and got responce in my flutter code 
print("this is responce from firebase $resp"); as a result 
this is responce from firebase Instance of 'HttpsCallableResult'
and firebase console URL responce:
{"error":{"message":"Bad Request","status":"INVALID_ARGUMENT"}}

Comment: @ParthBhanderi I edited the answer to show you how the call and response should be declared. I believe you were messing the call parameters, so the call was not matched with the function you published. I hope it fixes your problem

Comment: yes, i got the issue my firebase function works fine. thanks for help me.

Answer (score 7):

You must explicity put the attribute "data" in the json of response.

Like:

```
response.send({
"status" : success,
"data" : "some... data"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can convert to .onCall type function if you want to call function by it's name. [aldobaie's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57713052/8351061)

or for onRequest type function:

we need to call it as RESTful APIs.

While deploying to firebase, we'll get functions URL

or we can get function URL from dashboard of functions from firebase.

[image]

URL is in formate of:

> https://us-central1-< projectName >.cloudfunctions.net/< functionName >

call it as any other RESTful API. plus point of using it as API is that data field in response isn't mandatory and freedom of response formate.

Comment: I would not recommend this - you need to make your function public and won't be able to use AppCheck, meaning that anyone on the internet can call it.