# Get response firebase functions from app with Emulators

Tags: javascript, angular, google-cloud-functions, firebase-tools

How can I get the response of a Firebase function from my app with Emulators?

I am trying the following:

component.ts

```
getInfo() {
    const functions = getFunctions();
    connectFunctionsEmulator(functions, 'localhost', 5001);

    const getInfo = httpsCallable(functions, 'getFileInformation');
    getInfo()
    .then( (result) => {
      console.log(result.data);
    })
  }
```

component.html

```
<button (click)="getInfo()">Get file information</button>
```

Here the function:

```
export const getFileInformation = functions.https.onRequest( (req, res) => {

  return cors( req, res, () => {

    const urls = [
      `url1`,
      `url2`,
      `url3`
    ];

    const urlsCalls: any[] = [];
    const resultados: any[] = [];

    urls.forEach( url => {
      urlsCalls.push(axios.get(url));
    });

    Promise.allSettled(urlsCalls)
    .then( response => {
      response.map( (element: any) => {
        const item = element.value.data;
        resultados.push(item);
      });
      console.log(resultados);
      res.json(resultados);
    })
    .catch( error => {
      console.log(error);
    });

  } );


});
```

function url:

```
http://localhost:5001/[myProject]/us-central1/getFileInformation
```

When I click the button, the function is executed, here is the evidence in the Function Emulators:

[image]

That is, the function is executed and returns results, but I don't know how to capture them from my app.

The error I get is:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): FirebaseError: Response is missing data field.
FirebaseError: Response is missing data field.
```

Comment: You're calling a Callable function, but implement a regular HTTP function. In order to be able to use `httpsCallable`, the server-side must be a `functions.https.onCall`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57711368/callable-cloud-function-error-response-is-missing-data-field